# Error retrieving coordinates on a Motorola Defy+ (MB526)

Tags: android, geolocation, location, hardware

First of all, I apologize for the English, I don't know how to write english very well.

I am creating an application that should show the user's location on the map. As per the documentation, I've created my listener and added an overlay with my location.

In all other Android devices my application works fine, including the Motorola Defy (MB525), but in (MB526) apparently it does not receive a differente coordinate.

```
public class TesteMapActivity extends MapActivity {

    private LocationManager locationManager;

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
        criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
        criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
        criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);

        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 0, 0, locationListener);

        MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        MapController mapController = mapView.getController();
        mapView.setSatellite(false);
        mapView.setStreetView(false);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        mapController.setZoom(16);
    }

    private LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {

        int i = 0;

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) { }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) { }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) { }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            i++;
            animeTo(location, i);
        }
    };

    public void animeTo(Location location, int i) {
        TextView txtCoordenadas = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCoordenadas);

        txtCoordenadas.setText(i + " " + location.getLatitude() + ", " + location.getLongitude());

        MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        MapController mapController = mapView.getController();

        if (mapView.getOverlays().size() >= 1) {
            mapView.getOverlays().removeAll(mapView.getOverlays());
        }

        List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
        Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ponto);
        OtemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new OtemizedOverlay(drawable, TesteMapActivity.this);

        Double lat = location.getLatitude() * 1E6;
        Double log = location.getLongitude() * 1E6;

        GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(lat.intValue(), log.intValue());
        OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "Minha Localização", "Latitude: " + lat + " Longitude: " + log);

        itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
        mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);

        mapController.animateTo(point);
    }
}

public class OtemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {
    private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
    private Context mContext;

    public OtemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker) {
        super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
    }

    public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
        mOverlays.add(overlay);
        populate();
    }

    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
        return mOverlays.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return mOverlays.size();
    }

    public OtemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context) {
        super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onTap(int index) {
        OverlayItem item = mOverlays.get(index);
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        dialog.setTitle(item.getTitle());
        dialog.setMessage(item.getSnippet());
        dialog.show();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Thank you.

Comment: What you mean exactly by "*apparently it does not receive a differente coordinate*" ? It either receives something different or not... You mean 1) the coordinates are always fixed even if you move around; or 2) the coordinates received are different from the ones received by other phones; or 3) something else (please explain better). If you need more help, I speak pt-BR as well.

Comment: David tks for yout help.

The problem is the choice 2) the coordinates received are different from the ones received by other phones. One solution that I find are kill the Listenner and start again, but is it a WorkArround.


Bom dia, o problema que encontrei é realmente a segunda opção informada pelo senhor, fiz uma gambiarra para resolver parando o Listenner e executando de novo, mais esta é uma solução muito ruim.

Comment: 1) Did you already try to debug your app? 2) Did you try logging your `onLocationChanged` method and not use the `animeTo` (to make sure the problem is not in your animeTo method); 3) What you mean by kill (stopping, as you say in pt-BR) and start again (executing, as you say in pt-BR) the listener? Are you _unregistering_ and registering again, or are you stopping the app? Please be precise 4) I'm leaning towards a hardware specificity. The Defy+ probably returns a very coarse location because you're setting COARSE and POWER_LOW. But we can only be sure if you provide more details.

Comment: Finally, please read this: http://sscce.org/ --- Try testing your code one step at a time. Post the coordinates returned in `onLocationChanged` by logging them. Post here.

Comment: Hi David,
1)Yes, and the listenner continues work all the time. He changes the location, but in any moment that I don't get see. He's not change the location.
2)I made this for tests and the problem persist.
3)For this test I killed the app and started again, and the map continues show the old location.   
4)I inserted this problem into Motorola forum, and the Mr. Greg (Android Technology Evangelist Developer Platforms Motorola Mobility) said that I need make a workaround for a good operation in this device. I believe that this problem is a Hardware problem into Defy+, but I still can't prove.

Comment: Then we can only tell more if you explain the exactly nature of the workaround and exactly why it's necessary. Otherwise we will be left guessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, David and Kaneto, Paulo I thanks you that help me a lot.

I found a solution, if you have a same problem use this to resolve.

change your method animeTo to a AsyncTask().

```
public void animeTo(Location location) {
     new AsyncTask() {  
            protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {  

                //your code   
                return null;  
            }  
        }.execute(new Void[0]);
}
```

This works fine on my tests.

Again I apologize for the English, I don't know how to write english very well.

Answer (score 0):

Defy+ Hardware/Default Configuration has a bug.

You can have a solution for your device on [this link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1458285).

If you are developing an app for this device only, the best way to think is forget it. Defy+ is a mess, and useless piece of junk.

I suggest not kill the Listener directly, It will mess with the location, and will make other devices work bad. So it's better have 1% of problems, than 100% working bad.